# How to get URL from a QR code via ZBar SDK and and show the user

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, zbar

A simple App is being made that scans a QR code and then shows the user what the QR code is that they have scanned.

ZBAR SDK is being used.

The PROBLEM:- 
Once the App has been scanned, it takes the user to the website straight away. I need it to store the QR code in the App then take the user to another page in the app showing them the web address they have scanned. The user then has the opportunity to go to that site using a button now setup to use that link.

So how can I stop the ZBAR SDK from sending the user to the website straight away and get it to store the link so I can use it?

Can it be done?